# How do I input a quadratic equation in C++?

Tags: c++, math

We were given an assignment to program the following, which I have been trying to figure out how to solve for the last 2 hours but to no avail.

> How do you actually solve a complex formula having different operations in one mathematical expression?

> For you to properly understand which of the operations are to be solved in order, try recreating the quadratic equation, ax^2 + bx + c, in C++ on your own!

> **Instructions**:

> 1. The value of a, b, c, and x are already provided for you in the code editor. Remake the formula using C++'s math functions and operators and store it into one variable.

> 2. Print the value of the variable that stores the formula. To understand which to actually solve first in the equation, try tracing it out by yourself and manually solve it and see if your answer match that of the sample output.

> **Sample output:** `16`

TL;DR I am told to recreate the *quadratic equation* on my own using the given variables with their values.

Here is my current output which failed:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void) {
    
    int a = 2;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 4;
    int x = 2;

    // TODO:
    // 1. Compute for the result of the quadratic equation
    //    using the variables provided above and the math library
    
    double result;
    result = (a * x + b * x) pow(2, 2) + c;

    // 2. Print the output required by the output sample
    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out `4` when it should be 16.

Comment: `result = (a * x + b * x) pow(2, 2) + c;` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do here? Did you want to do: `result = a * x * x + b * x + c;` perhaps? Also, using `pow()` in this case is overkill, you can just do simple multiplication.

Comment: This is actually quite embarrassing for me to ask a stupid question like this. Thank you so much, this is the answer it is looking for, Elijay and Ruks!

Comment: Your teacher needs to brush up on terminology. `ax^2 + bx + c` is not an equation - an equation defines an *equality*, like `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`, that *equates* things (hence the name); computing the value of a formula is not "solving" it; and you can't store a formula in a number.

Comment: Regarding your question's title, you only need to input the *coefficients* of the polynomial, such as `a, b,` and `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this code:

```
result = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;
```

Comment: Or, to avoid having to call the `pow` function: `result = a * x * x + b * x + c;`